# How do I get yacc/bison and/or lex/flex to restart scanning after something like token substitution?

Tags: c, parsing, bison, yacc, flex-lexer

Is there a way to force bison and/or flex to restart scanning after I replace some token with something else?

My particular example would be with replacement for a specific word/string.  If I want a word of `hello` to be replaced by `echo hello`, how can I get flex or bison to replace `hello` and then start parsing again (to pick up 2 words instead of just one).  So it would be like:

- Get token WORD (which is a string type)
- If `hello`, replace token value with `echo hello`
- Restart parsing entire input (which is now `echo hello`)
- Get token WORD (`echo`)
- Get token WORD (`hello`)

I've seen very tempting functions like `yyrestart()`, but I don't really understand what that function in particular really accomplishes.  Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Update 4/23/2010**

One kind of hack-and-slash solution I've ended up using is for each `word` that comes through, I check an "alias" array.  If the `word` has an alias, I replace the value of the word (using, for example, `strcopy($1,aliasval)`), and mark an `aliasfound` flag.

Once the entire line of input is parsed once, if the `aliasfound` flag is true, I use `yy_scan_string()` to switch the buffer state to the input with expanded aliases, and call `YYACCEPT`.

So then it jumps out to the main function and I call `yyparse()` again, with the buffer still pointing to my string.  This continues until no aliases are found.  Once all of my grammar actions are complete, I call `yyrestart(stdin)` to go back to "normal" mode.

If anyone knows how I can effectively expand my words w/ their alias values, inject into `stdin` (or some other method), and basically expand all aliases (even nested) as I go, that would be awesome.  I was playing around with `yypush_buffer_state()` and `yypop_buffer_state()`, along with `yy_switch_to_buffer()`, but I couldn't get "inline" substitution with continued parsing working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an "answer" based on what I ended up doing. Want to mark this question as answered.

**Update 4/23/2010**

One kind of hack-and-slash solution I've ended up using is for each word that comes through, I check an "alias" array. If the word has an alias, I replace the value of the word (using, for example, strcopy($1,aliasval)), and mark an aliasfound flag.

Once the entire line of input is parsed once, if the aliasfound flag is true, I use yy_scan_string() to switch the buffer state to the input with expanded aliases, and call YYACCEPT.

So then it jumps out to the main function and I call yyparse() again, with the buffer still pointing to my string. This continues until no aliases are found. Once all of my grammar actions are complete, I call yyrestart(stdin) to go back to "normal" mode.

If anyone knows how I can effectively expand my words w/ their alias values, inject into stdin (or some other method), and basically expand all aliases (even nested) as I go, that would be awesome. I was playing around with yypush_buffer_state() and yypop_buffer_state(), along with yy_switch_to_buffer(), but I couldn't get "inline" substitution with continued parsing working...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the place to fix this is the lexer.  I would suggest using flex, which supports a state machine (called "[Start Conditions](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/flex_11.html)" in the flex documentation).  You change states using `BEGIN`, and the states need to be defined in the definitions section.

So, for example, you could have a rule like

```
<INITIAL>hello    BEGIN(in_echo); yyless(0); return (WORD_ECHO);
<in_echo>hello    BEGIN(0); return (WORD_HELLO);
```

`yyless()` truncates the `yytext` to the given value, so this puts the entire input back into the stream.

I haven't tried this out myself, but I think this is the structure of the solution you want.